# Webview webBackForwardList doesn't store all the URL history

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Recently I got informed that my hybrid Android application doesn't work properly.

The complaint is that when they press the back button on the device, It should go back to a previous webview url.

But It goes back to a url which is like the user pressed back button twice.

So When I took a look at logs

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    WebBackForwardList URL = webView.copyBackForwardList();
    for(int i = 0;i < URL.getSize(); i++){
        Log.d("URL list : " + i, URL.getItemAtIndex(i).getUrl());
    }
}
```

And with a simulator, It shows all the list of URL that I've entered.

Which is working properly

```
D/URL list : 0: //https://www.blabla.com/ //First webview
D/URL list : 1: //https://www.blabla.com/catalog/category/view/id/999/ //Second webview
D/URL list : 2: //https://www.blabla.com/brand/bla.html //Third webview
D/URL list : 3: //https://www.blabla.com/44444444.html //Fourth webview
```

But with a real device like Samsung Galaxy S6, The third and first Urls are missing.

```
URL list : 0: //https://www.blabla.com/catalog/category/view/id/999/ //Second webview
URL list : 1: //https://www.blabla.com/44444444.html //Fourth webview
```

It used to work fine several weeks ago.
Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Android device has Chrome version 63.0.3239.111 installed, webview's back-forward-list doesn't work properly. Disable or revert to earlier version of Chrome did the trick for me. However, that solution may not be suitable for everyone. In that case, wait for the next release of Chrome and retest. Good luck either way.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it is Chrome issue. I will wait for next version of Chrome then.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static WebBackForwardList getHistoricalList(WebView webView) {
    return webView.copyBackForwardList();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    WebBackForwardList URL = getHistoricalList(webView)
    for(int i = 0;i < URL.getSize(); i++){
        Log.d("URL list : " + i, URL.getItemAtIndex(i).getUrl());
    }
}
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: That's the exact same code OP has, with it moved to an external method instead. It won't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if there are missing URL's in the backforwardlist, it isn't going to help going back